# IE 8 and olders don't display IMG tag that has long SRC value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to load an image by ajax then display it by setting `src` attribute of the `img` tag with the value format `data:image/png;base64,some_real_byte_data_here...`.

Everything works smoothly on Firefox & Chrome, but IE 8. Only small image can be displayed by this way.

Server requires the huge data to compute & plot image, hence sending data via a LINK in SRC (GET method) is impossible.

Any idea on this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because for IE8 and below:

> [Data URIs cannot be larger than 32,768 characters.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That's partially correct. Data URIs are supported from IE8+. On IE8 they cannot be larger than 32 Kb. This limitations has been removed from IE9+.

Comment: @Ramhound I think the point xiaoyi is trying to make is that the statement is meaningless to try and apply to IE7 and IE6 because they don't support data URIs *at all*.

Comment: @rob: looks like BoltClock edited it *at the same time* and his edit clashed with yours by accident. Please don't attribute to malice what can be explained by unfortunate coincidence instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems that I must change the handling at both server & client sides.